# Javascript in jsp page outputs 'true' when var is defined in function

Tags: javascript, jsf

I have a webpage using a javascript. The code sample:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var shown = 0;

function showOrHidePanel()
{
    var isComplete = '<h:outputText value="#{general.sessionCompleted}" />';

    if (isComplete == true){
        if (shown==0) {
            Richfaces.showModalPanel('pnl',{width:550, top:200});
        }
        shown = 1;
    } else {
        if (shown == 1) {
            Richfaces.hideModalPanel('pnl');
        }
        shown = 0;
    }
    return;
}
</script>

<a4j:region>
    <h:form>
        <a4j:poll id="poll" interval="10000" reRender="pnl" action="#{general.checkOnDrcSession}"
            oncomplete="showOrHidePanel()" />
    </h:form>
</a4j:region>
```

The effect i'm trying to achieve is to make the modalpanel be shown by the polling component only once whenever `sessionCompleted` becomes true (So it wont show the flickering page effect on every re-show of the modalpanel.
But i'm a javascript newb and i'm afraid that, in addition to this not working correctly, I get a 'true' text at the top of the page.

When i take down the var `isComplete = '<h:output...` declaration, the 'true' text disappears.

Thanks for the help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get rid of those singlequotes.

```
var isComplete = <h:outputText value="#{general.sessionCompleted}" />;
```

You want to end up with

```
var isComplete = true; // or false
```

and not with

```
var isComplete = 'true'; // or 'false'
```

in the generated output.

Alternatively, you can also just do

```
if (<h:outputText value="#{general.sessionCompleted}" />) {
```

Comment: TnX @BalusC, I still see the 'true' (or 'false') text on the web page. Is there anything specific I should be sorrounding the <script> tag with?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing isComplete to just:

```
var isComplete = Boolean("#{general.sessionCompleted}");
```

This should (in theory) create a boolean value based on the text that is rendered by the server.

Comment: Right, Ben is using JSP, not Facelets.

Comment: gotcha, my bad. my experience with other web frameworks lead me to believe that the #{ } was enough for accessing server side variables.